# Add numbers in foreach Loop PHP

Tags: php, loops, foreach, opencart

I have a `foreach loop` which lists through a number of products in OpenCart. I want to return the total in a variable called `$subTotal` - however it only returns the last product price, should it be `=+` or `+++` all return errors.

**Update** - I should add that `$product['total']` alone will echo `£100` for example (not `&pound;100` it just echos the currency symbol and numeric)

```
<?
####
// START ***********
####
$subTotal=0;
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $subTotal=$product['total'];
?>

 <!--<?=$product['total']?>-->

<?
    $subTotal++;
}
####
// END ***********
####
?>
<?=$subTotal?>
```

Comment: Your edit includes characters.. you first need to make the string a number and remove all data except the 0.0 decimals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

You could do this by

```
<?php 
// create vars
$x=$product['total'];

// remove pound signs etc
$x=str_replace("£", "", $x);
$x=str_replace("&pound;", "", $x);

// loop and or add to the variable subTotal
$subTotal += $x;

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $subTotal+= preg_replace('/[^\d\.]/','',$product['total']);

}
echo $subTotal;
?>
```

in your foreach statement

Comment: Hi edit includes characters.. you first need to make the string a number and remove all data except the 0.0 decimals

Answer (score 0):

```
$subTotal += $product['total'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$subTotal += $product['total'];`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $subTotal += $product['total'];
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you are setting `$subTotal` to be equal to `$product['total']`. You need to add `$product['total']` to `$subTotal`.

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $subTotal=+$product['total']; ?>
}
```